# Reset multiple variables most effective way

Tags: c#, wpf, variables, boolean

I have C# WPF app and i wanna know what is most effective way

User can do some settings which is gonna store to variables

```
bool val1 = false;
bool val2 = false;

string val3 = "";
string vak4 = "";

int val5 = ""; #etc
```

Problem is there is maybe like 30-40 of these values. And i need when user goes somewhere else in application by button on different view (mvp pattern) all of these values wíll reset to their default values.

So im curious if there is more effective way to do that than put all this variables on click event on button and give them their default values back.

Maybe like putting them into dictionary or list? And just do loop which sets all of them to default value?  Maybe put them into array? Or what is most effective solution in this case?

Comment: Your focus should be on reducing the number of variables you need.

Comment: you can decide to set default values on load of the controls. But same time you need to keep a static variable to determine whether session needs to persist data. If that variable is true then do not load data defaults, else load. by session variable, I mean a static object.

Comment: why dont you write a reset method?? Call the reset method when ever you need.

Comment: If your variable names actually have number suffixes like `val1` and `val2`, maybe you should have an array instead?

Comment: @Ugur i have reset method written. Just curious what is most effective, if its just reset them one by one, or in some loop if therey in array, list, etc.

Comment: @Wyck They dont.

Comment: Maybe if this is some kind of _Settings_ object (composed of dozens of discrete variables) then you could simply reassign your settings object to a new instance of `Settings.Default` or something like that.

Comment: Are these variables fields on a class or something? Fields on your view, model, or presenter for example? And they're of different types like you've shown in the code block?

Comment: Have you considered implementing IEditableObject on the class that stores your values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terms of (micro-benchmark) performance, the most effective way is to simply set the variables to their default value one by one. You could for example do this in a method called `Reset()` or something.

In terms of code maintenance, you'd probably be better off using a `Dictionary<string, object>` or something that you can simply call `Clear()` on.

This is *not* a performance bottleneck issue so you should choose the most elegant and easy-to-use approach. There is something called premature optimization. It might be an idea to read up on this.